# Assembly.LoadFile() and crash

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I use Assembly.LoadFile(string path) to load assembly to C# program. It works perfectly on my PC and two notebooks but... when I tried to send this app to my friend it crashed just after this call without any exceptions. We use same versions of .NET Framework, everything must be fine. I cant understand what happens. No exceptions, no errors, just "silent" return.
I also tried to use LoadFrom but nothing changed.
I use absolute path for dll files

```
public LoadedType[] LoadFrom(string path)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
        }
```

and calling method is

```
Loader loader = new Loader();
        string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        List<string> corrupted = new List<string>();

        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            try
            {
                LoadedType[] loadedTypes = loader.LoadFrom(path);
                MessageBox.Show("loaded");

                if (loadedTypes.Length == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach (LoadedType loadedT in loadedTypes)
                {
                    AvailableTypes.Add(loadedT);
                }
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
                corrupted.Add(Path.GetFileName(path));
            }
        }
```

MessageBox does not appear.
Could somebody explain me whats wrong and why this code works on three PCs and does not work on another two PCs with the same Framework version?

Comment: anything in the fusion logs?

Comment: I cant see it. On my PC everything works well.

Comment: Maybe your foreach never executes! Check the path and see if it is actually has something in it!

Comment: Yes it has. I checked it with a MessageBox inside LoadFrom method

Comment: Using GetCurrentDirectory() is a Really Bad Idea.  Worst kind of global variable, you don't control it.  Your app falls over when it loads an arbitrary DLL.  Or finds none at all.  Always locate files from a known directory, relative from your EXE file.  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location gets you a decent path for example.

Comment: `Assembly.Load()` will also fail if it cannot find references that the DLL being loaded depends on. Make sure your friend has all of the necessary DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the code  above you can not know if is there an exception or not, because you catch just exception of type `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, add another `catch(Exception ex)`.

Check that `string[] paths` is not empty.

check that these assemblies are not used by another process.

check that you have access to read these assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider other types of possible exceptions as well:

```
try
{
    // Ignore assemblies we can't load. They could be native, etc...
   Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
}
catch (Win32Exception) { }
catch (ArgumentException) { }
catch (FileNotFoundException) { }
catch (PathTooLongException) { }
catch (BadImageFormatException) { }
catch (SecurityException) { }
```